# How to CONCAT and COUNTIF in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data that needs to be equated accordingly in Excel.

I was expecting to get `Still studying: 21002` as `=COUNTIF(B2:B13011, "Still studying")` gives `21002` and I want to concatenate that result with a defined strings: "Still studying" but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

This is the equation I came up with

```
=CONCAT("Still studying: ", =COUNTIF(G2:B13011, "Still studying"))
```

Like python maybe you can do this by combining strings and do `print("Still studying: {}".format(variable_in_list)` or alike

Thank you for looking at my problem.

===============================================================

**UPDATED**: (Thank you to JvdV)

This code works

`="Still studying: "&COUNTIF(G2:G13011, "Still studying")`

Comment: Maybe just `="Still studying: "&COUNTIF(G2:G13011, "Still studying")`. Note how I think you have a typo in your range `G2:B13....`. Note your own formula came close but would work if you remove the inner '=' and fix your range.

Comment: Hey! That works. I had a typo on my Cell Range when posting this. Thank you so much this is really a lifesaver!